# how identify FAT16 or FAT32 from boot sector

Tags: c, filesystems, fat32, fat16

Is there a way to identify the type of a FAT partition (if it is 16 or 32) only by reading its boot sector?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not by reading the boot sector - You need to look into the file system itself.

Find the number of clusters. The file system subtype can be determined by this number:

> less than 4086: FAT12
>
> equal or more than 4086: FAT16
>
> more than 65525: FAT32

Comment: by the filesystem itself, you mean inside the mbr of the device right?

Comment: MBR is the first sector of the *device* - You need to look into the first sector of the *partition*, though. That would typically be LBA 63

Comment: The numbers are off. Here is the correct count from the FAT specifications: 


If(CountofClusters < 4085) {
/* Volume is FAT12 */
} else if(CountofClusters < 65525) {
/* Volume is FAT16 */
} else {
/* Volume is FAT32 */
}

Answer (score 1):

If the sectors per FAT word in the FAT12/FAT16 BPB is zero, it is FAT32. (Regardless of the actual FAT size, FAT32 uses the EBPB's sectors per FAT **dword**.) Likewise, if the number of root directory entries word is zero, it is FAT32.